# pymqi connection calls fail in subprocesses on osx *and* the exception kills the python shell

Tags: python, macos, ibm-mq, pymqi

On Linux, the following pairs of commands both work:

```
$ python -c "import pymqi; pymqi.connect('QM1', 'DEV.APP.SVRCONN', 'localhost(1414)', user='xxx', password='xxx')"  # command 1
$ bash -c "python -c \"import pymqi; pymqi.connect('QM1', 'DEV.APP.SVRCONN', 'localhost(1414)', user='xxx', password='xxx')\""  # command 2
```

On OSX, the first one succeeds and the second fails with this output:

```
TENDTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/wolfson/.local/share/virtualenvs/xxx-xWWWLtqs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymqi/__init__.py", line 3214, in connect
    qmgr.connect_tcp_client(queue_manager or '', CD(), channel, conn_info, user, password)
  File "/Users/wolfson/.local/share/virtualenvs/xxx-xWWWLtqs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymqi/__init__.py", line 1772, in connect_tcp_client
    self.connect_with_options(name, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wolfson/.local/share/virtualenvs/xxx-xWWWLtqs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymqi/__init__.py", line 1747, in connect_with_options
    raise MQMIError(rv[1], rv[2])
pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2009: FAILED: MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN
```

(Note that weird `TEND` prefix before `Traceback`. Weird!)

Not only that, but if I just run `bash -c python` and then do `import pymqi; pymqi.connect('QM1', 'DEV.APP.SVRCONN', 'localhost(1414)', user='xxx', password='xxx')` in the python shell, I get the same exception and the Python process itself exits.

This does not seem to happen when running the sample programs in `/opt/mqm/samp/bin/`.

I assume this has something to do with some OSX thing, but … what? and is there a workaround?

EDIT: This is not related to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. There is no nested build-time error:

```
% bash -c "pipenv run pip install pymqi"
Requirement already satisfied: pymqi in /Users/wolfson/.local/share/virtualenvs/xxx-xWWWLtqs/lib/python3.11/site-packages (1.12.10)
```

And it is (obviously) possible to import `pymqi.pymqe` in the nested shell.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to the System Integrity Protection feature in macOS. Certain executables (including shell scripts) don't inherit DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.

To see this is action:

1. Open a terminal
2. Run `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`
3. Run `bash`
4. Run `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` needs to be set to pick up the MQ client runtime dynamic libraries that by default are in `/opt/mqm/lib64`

Comment: This is definitely true, but as someone _not_ running the OP's software stack and experiencing their problem, the relevance isn't obvious. Which part of the OP's code requires DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: This is not related to $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, because if it were, I wouldn't be able to import `pymqi.pymqe` at all. It may well be related to SIP, but if it is, that isn't the reason.

Comment: This is an execution time related issue, ie. `pymqi.pymqe` has already been built with a `pip install`. If you want to see the build time `pymqi.pymqe` error, try running `pip install` in the nested bash shell.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `pymqi.pymqe`. It is built and installed. It can be imported. There is no build time error. I'm sorry this diagnosis is simply not correct.

Comment: That is correct, it is a runtime related problem, not build time because you have already built with all the paths and library paths correctly set.